# How to call global static method from class static method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, static, global, class-method

The following program compiles et executes just fine in recent versions of C#, where a Main function is not necessary:

```cs
Module2.SayHelloDouble();

static class Module1
{
    public static void SayHello()
        => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}

static class Module2
{
    public static void SayHelloDouble()
    {
        Module1.SayHello();
        Module1.SayHello();
    }
}
```

However, if I make the `SayHello` method "global static", the program does not compile anymore (verified with C# 12 / NET 8).

[image: cannot access global static method from class method]

Is there a way to access a "global scope static method" from inside a class method ? Or is that simply impossible ?

Comment: You removed the `public` access modifier from `SayHello()`. I imagine that's your issue

Comment: dotnetfiddle marks this as quite the opposite of a "global" function: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JH0xQU > _"The **local** function 'SayHello' is declared but never used"_ (emphasis by me)

Comment: *error CS8801: Cannot use local variable or local function 'SayHello' declared in a top-level statement in this context.*

Comment: @maccettura You can not add a `public` modifier to `SayHello`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, if I make the SayHello method "global static"

The thing is that you are not making it global in any way, you are making it a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) (basically vice versa from what you have expected) for `Program.$Main` method which will be generated for [top-level statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements):

```
Module2.SayHelloDouble();
static void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
```

[Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics) is a feature introduced with C# 9 which allows to skip some boilerplate code for [`Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line) method declaration and make compiler it do for you.

Basically the following:

```
Module2.SayHelloDouble();

static void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");

static class Module2
{
    public static void SayHelloDouble()
    {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

Is turned by compiler to something like the following (a bit simplified, [full decompilation @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDILIHtgFcA2BTGAOgGUBDATwAk8cd0ARdLAI3wAoBKAbmWSjgBsAAigAWIWSo06nIQF4AfCLgBONgCJqtdAEJ13Xkn7DYQjNnwxkAb2RD7IgMzKT4yVrqMW7DnYe2kByEAX2RgoA===)):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
internal class Program
{
    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
        Module2.SayHelloDouble();
        // your local method, accessible in the generated Main method
        static void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static void <<Main>$>g__SayHello|0_0()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}

internal static class Module2
{
    public static void SayHelloDouble()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it available inside `Module2` & inside the top-level statement
then you can do the following trick:

```
SayHello();
Module2.SayHelloDouble();

static class Module2
{
    public static void SayHelloDouble()
    {
        Program.SayHello();
        Program.SayHello();
    }
}

public static partial class Program 
{ 
    public static void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
```

- Define a partial static `Program` class and move there the `SayHello`
- Don't forget to add `public` accessor for the `SayHello` method
- Call `SayHello` through the `Program` class inside the `SayHelloDouble` method

---

**UPDATE #1**

With `using static Program;` you can eliminate the need to prepend the `SayHello` calls with `Program.` inside the `SayHelloDouble`. But the solution gets uglier and uglier...

```
using static Program;

SayHello();
Module2.SayHelloDouble();

static class Module2
{
    public static void SayHelloDouble()
    {
        SayHello();
        SayHello();
    }
}

public static partial class Program 
{ 
    public static void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: @Fildor Yes that's correct. I've extended the post with your comment and proposed another alternative which is ugly...